# How can I use avg aggregation for keyword typed field in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi tried some solutions but due to lack of elasticsearch experience i could concluded.

First of all I have *index* like this;

```
field1 | field2 | **status: 200, response_time: 2** (type of this row keyword)
//other rows omitted for brevity
```

My business requirement is averaging response_time seconds. I want to parse `status: 200, response_time: 2` row and get time from with regexp then do averaging.

I tried it like:

```
private RestHighLevelClient client;

  public void averaging() {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index_name");
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    AvgAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.avg("response_time_average")
        .field("doc['Message.keyword']").script(
            new Script(
                "def value = doc['Message.keyword']; return Integer.parseInt(value.split('regexp'))"));
    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregation);

    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

    try {
      SearchResponse search = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
      Avg agg = search.getAggregations().get("response_time_average");
      double value = agg.getValue();

      //value returns as _infinity_      
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

I don't have enough information about elasticsearch jargon. I tried a lot of solutions but I think this one is more close to solution.

My elasticservice client version is 7.3.1
thank you :)